# Check multiple values on a cell and copy one

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excell in which one of the rows looks like the following:

> 09001 | 09003 | 09017 | 173018 | 8199
>
> 09001 | 81009 | 173005 | 6709 | 15005

Now, what I need is a formula for a cell that will check if I have some specific values (For example, 09003 and 173005) and copy them to the actuall cell.

The values I look for won't be repeated, It will be just one of them in the cell, that should make it easier but I havent been lucky trying...

Result expected per examples above:

> | 09003 |
>
> | 173007|

Comment: Just to be clear: Is `09001 | 09003 | 09017 | 173018 | 8199` in a single cell (as the title of your question implies) or is each number in its own cell? (as the first sentence in your question implies)

Comment: Do you try VBA?

Comment: Hi @cybermetic.nomad. All the numbers are on the same cell.

Comment: I would like to archieve this through Formula, as it has to be shared through O365 and it doesnt accept macros quite well. Is it possible? Or will I have to use VBA on any case? (Both ways I wouldnt know were to start, I've tried with IFs and SEARCH commands

Answer (score 1):

This is my answer:

**Formula for 9003:**

```
=IFERROR(IF(FIND($B$1,A2)>0,B1,0),"-")
```

**Formula for 173007:**

```
=IFERROR(IF(FIND($C$1,A2)>0,C1,0),"-")
```

**Results Structure:**

[image]

**Formula for both number in one cell:**

```
=IFERROR(IF(FIND("9003",A1)>0,"9003",0),"-") & " " & IFERROR(IF(FIND("173007",A1)>0,"173007",0),"-")
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Many thanks!
Would it be possible for it to be in the same cell? Checking in B both for a 9003 and 173007?

Answer (score 1):

For example, "09003" can be extracted using the following Excel functions:

Say B3 is cell containing source string:

```
09001 | 09003 | 09017 | 173018 | 8199
```

Then:

```
//                      find start of target string
B4 contains formula 1 [ =LEFT(FIND("09003",B3)) ] // "09003" could also be passed as a cell reference
//                      find end of target string
C4 contains formula 2 [ =RIGHT(FIND("|", B3, B4)) ]
//                      extract string using endpoints
D4 contains result    [ =MID(B3, B4, (B4-C4)+1) ]
```

[image]